# deployment cost different in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

```
contract A {
   function b_1Y() public pure returns (uint) {
       return 1;
   }
}

contract B {
   function b_1X() public pure returns (uint) {
       return 1;
   }
}
```

Deployment cost of `A` is much smaller than `B`..

Why ? I know selector of `b_1Y` ends up being `0000....` and it has to do with that, but more explanation would be good in terms of assembly opcodes.